# IBM System X3550 M2 | Virtualization is not supported

Tags: virtualization, ibm-server

Background:

I had a server donated to me and its a IBM System x3550 M2 Xeon E5506 @ 2.13 GHz. I installed Windows Server 2012 because I was testing and messing around with it. I was going to install ESXi 5.1 but for some reason I was not able to get the server to read off any ESX media I put in it, (CD, USB...).

So I am currently using WS 2012 and I have VM Workstation installed for creating some virtual machines and all went well.

Issue:

I went to boot my machines the other day, and I got an error saying "64-bit guest operating systems are not supported by this host and will not run."

This did not make sense. I rebooted and checked the bios, the setting is enabled and I saved the settings and I'm getting no where with this issue.

I even upgraded the firmware on this box and enabled the setting again and nothing...
Virtualization worked before and now its not working, I'm stumped.

Comment: Do you have any other hypervisor based software installed?  See [this link](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2328705) for reference.  Also can you post any log files?  That processor does support [VT and other virtualization options](http://ark.intel.com/products/37096/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5506-4M-Cache-2_13-ghz-4_80-gts-Intel-qpi) so an application change or improper shutdown may be the culprit.

Comment: The only 'hypervisor' software Is IBM's embedded hypervisor, but that requires a USB flash device I do not have... Other then that, I have nothing installed.